# Looking for an phrase or illustration to describe someone who doesn't understand the value of something

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase or short illustration to describe someone completely missing the value of something or someone, e.g. a Sahara tribesman who stumbles across an iPhone and uses it to block a hole in his mud hut...

Comment: A story? Can you confirm you want an actual story as opposed to an expression or even a short quote?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure a short story or an illustration request is on-topic for this site. Let's wait for others to weigh in.

Comment: @TusharRaj agree ... phrases, word usage and/or idioms would be appropriate.

Comment: The purpose of the device was completely "lost on him".

Comment: Famous quote from Oscar Wilde: "A cynic is someone who knows the price of everything but the value of nothing."   Is this the kind of phrase you are looking for?  It does not fit your example.

Answer (score 1):

As in:

A sahara tribesmam stumbled across an iphone. Its use **was lost on him** as he used it to block a hole in his mud hut.

**be lost on (someone)**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+lost+on+(someone))

> To have little or no impact or effect on someone; to not be valued,
>   appreciated, or understood by someone.

Answer (score -1):

Repurposing.

Note that there's a value judgement hidden in the question. Do objects have 'intrinsic' value, or is their value entirely in the context of the user?

A discharged iPhone away from power and cell towers is merely an interesting mirror or a useful brick. That tribesman made the phone valuable to herself, thus adding value.